# Href link with OnClick event

Tags: joomla, href, bookmarks, window.open

i am having a link like below
    where on click of that twitter , i need to open the twitter page with the   message given in $markme_ddesc but instead when i click on the link , it simply moves to twitter.com without opening in a new window and with the message..

```
<a style="text-decoration:none;" href="http://www.twitter.com" onclick="window.open(\'http://twitter.com/home/?status=\'+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+\'-'.$markme_ddesc.'\');return false;">
```

Why so? how to resolve this?? Please help me..

Comment: does your rendered HTML code show proper URL location?

Comment: Sounds like there's an error in the JavaScript in your onclick statement. You should move it to a JavaScript function, so you can debug it.

Comment: <a style="text-decoration:none;" href="http://www.twitter.com" onclick="window.open(\'http://twitter.com/home/?status=\'+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+\'-'.$markme_ddesc.'\');return false;">

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<a style="text-decoration:none;" href="http://www.twitter.com" onClick="window.open('http://twitter.com/home/?status=\'+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+\'-'.$markme_ddesc);return false;">
```