# attaching the link of the article in href

Tags: javascript, html

i am having the link like

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/home/?status='.$markme_ddesc.'" onclick="OpenPopup(this.href); return false">Click Here to See Popup</a>
```

for bookmarking the article clicked to twitter .. The above one just add the articles message to twitter.. But i am trying to add my article link also to twitter,..
so i am using the location.href but its not working tat is its not showing me the articles site name..

THe below is the one i tried..

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/home/?status=\'+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+\'-'.$markme_ddesc.'" onclick="OpenPopup(this.href); return false">Click Here to See Popup</a>
```

Thanks i advance.. Help me to get out of this...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591282/href-link-with-onclick-event - Duplicate of your own question?

Comment: here in this post i have been discussing on EncodeURI component .. In the previous post i was searching for Onclick window open but i didnt find the correct solution .. SO i find the new way to use the link in the href itself with popup function .. But i am not aware of using encodeURI

Comment: Ok, sorry about that, didn't have my morning coffee yet. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you're using PHP, so you could use

```
'<a href="...' . urlencode(curPageURL()) . '-' . $markme_ddesc . '...'
```

where `curPageURL` is a [custom function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867278/php-determining-the-current-url/1867315#1867315) to get the full URL. (Or use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` if the domain is not needed.)

---

But if you really need to attach the URL from client side, you need to use Javascript.

```
<a id="xyz" href="http://twitter.com/home/?status=@PLACEHOLDER@-'.$markme_ddesc.'" … >
...

// onload:
var xyz = document.getElementById('xyz');
xyz.href = xyz.href.replace(/@PLACEHOLDER@/g, encodeURIComponent(location.href));
```

Of course this will fail if the client doesn't enable Javascript.

Comment: My 5 hrs risk in solving the above error came to an end.. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/home/?status=" desc="<?php echo $markme_ddesc; ?>" onclick="OpenPopup(this.href,this.desc); return false">Click Here to See Popup</a>

<script>
   function OpenPopup(href,desc){             
        var url = href + encodeURIComponent(location.href) + '-' + desc;
        //show popup here...
   }
</script>
```